# After rotate or change language dialog show again

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

Android Studio 3.6

I want to show dialog and hide it when press OK

I use LiveData and ViewModel.
So in my activity:

```
private lateinit var mainViewModel: MainViewModel


 mainViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

       // Call only when activity is visible to user or rotate device or change lanugage
        mainViewModel.getShowDialogLiveData().observe(this, Observer {
            if (it != null) {
                showDialog(it)
            }
        })

  private fun showDialog(text: String) {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        builder.setMessage(text)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", { dialog, id ->
                dialog.cancel()
                dialog.dismiss()
            })
        val alert = builder.create()
        alert.show()
}

fun pressButtonShowDialog() {
  mainViewModel.isSuccessPaymentConfirm(true)
}



 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, resultIntent: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode == PAYMENT_CONFIRM) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                mainViewM
            }
       }
}
```

and in my **MainViewModel.kt**

```
class MainViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
private val showDialogLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()

fun isSuccessPaymentConfirm(isSuccessPaymentConfirm: Boolean) {
        isShowDialogLiveData(true)

    }

fun isShowDialogLiveData(isShowDialogLiveData: Boolean) {
        this.isShowDialogLiveData.value = isShowDialogLiveData
        if (isShowDialogLiveData) {
            showDialogLiveData.value = "Message on dialog"
        }
}

fun getShowDialogLiveData(): LiveData<String> {
        return showDialogLiveData
}
```

And as result, when on activity press button then call `pressButtonShowDialog()`. As result call `mainViewModel.getShowDialogLiveData()`.
As result dialog is show. When I rotate device or change language the dialog is again show. Because again call `mainViewModel.getShowDialogLiveData()`.
Nice. It's good.

Then I pressed button OK and dialog is hide (`dialog.dismiss()`). Nice.

But when I **rotate** device or **change language** the dialog again show because **again call method** `mainViewModel.getShowDialogLiveData()`.

How I can avoid this?
When press button OK, the dialog must not show again.

Maybe I need to unsibsribe from `getShowDialogLiveData`. Or maybe `showDialogLiveData` must stop fire event. Or maybe has another solution?

Comment: when activity is recreated, it subscribes to the livedata again and gets the updated string which is not null and so the dialog is triggered again. your solutions are to use SingleLiveEvent, PublishSubject or something similar. Here are some discussions: https://old.reddit.com/r/androiddev/search?q=SingleLiveEvent&restrict_sr=on

Comment: @sonnet SingleLiveEvent not help. Because after rotate the dialog is gone. But I need the dialog to hide only AFTER press OK button.

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest add this line to the desired activity.

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|keyboard|orientation|screenSize"
```

Final code looks like this

```
  <activity android:name=".activities.xyz"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|keyboard|orientation|screenSize"/>
```

Comment: But what about change language?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this to your manifest for each activity

```
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

This will make it so that when you rotate that the activity does not end and reloads stuff[image]